# Can I disable Toolbar in specific theme?

Tags: 7, theming, toolbar

I have two active theme, and switching between them by themekey on specific paths.

theme #one is my main theme, and some contents load in theme #two in a modal box (lightbox2).
I need disable Toolbar on theme #two because it's load Toolbar too and I don't want it there.

my question is how can I disable Toolbar in theme #two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use [hook_page_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_page_alter/7) from within a module to unset `$page['page_top']['toolbar']` — you can't do it from within a theme.

There is a module for that: [Toolbar Visibility](http://drupal.org/project/toolbar_visibility).

Comment: There are only 10 sites using that module, so beware. Read the code.

Answer (score -1):

Or you can disable the 'toolbar' module for this.

https://www.ostraining.com/blog/drupal/adding-the-administration-menu-to-drupal-7-and-disabling-the-default-toolbar/

Is it the best way you think?
Or plan something like,

```
 1.
      if ($vars['page']['page_top']['toolbar']['#access']) {   
         $vars['page']['page_top']['toolbar']['#access'] = false;
      }
```

But I don't know where could you find the '$vars' from.